# Trying to use .SD inside by in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use the `.SD` to groupby inside a `data.table` to apply a function to a specific column. I'm gonna use iris dataset as an example.

Lets say I want to know how many unique `Sepal.Length` there is by species.

```
library(data.table)
obj="Species"
as.data.table(iris)[,length(unique(Sepal.Length)),by=.SD,.SDcols=obj]
```

It is important that I can supply `.SDcols` as an object, since I'm doing it programmatically. I also would like to know if it is possible using `data.table` instead of aggregate and/or xtabs solution.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could directly pass the 'obj' in `by` and get the `length` of `unique` elements of 'Sepal.Length' (`uniqueN`)

```
as.data.table(iris)[, .(uniqueLen = uniqueN(Sepal.Length)), by = obj]
```

---

If we wanted to go by the `.SDcols` route

```
as.data.table(iris)[, .SD[, .(uniqueLen = uniqueN(.SD[[1]])), by = obj], 
            .SDcols = c(obj, "Sepal.Length")]
```